# Cannot save django staticfiles to AWS S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I ran into a strange problem while deploying staticfiles to S3.

I installed boto3 and django-storages.

> Django: 2.1.2
>
> Python: 3.6.7

When running locally, my staticfiles settings were following,

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

When I want to save staticfiles to S3 bucket, I changed settings to

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'key'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'name'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

AWS_STATIC_LOCATION = 'static'
AWS_MEDIA_LOCATION  = 'media'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_STATIC_LOCATION)
STATIC_ROOT = STATIC_URL
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_MEDIA_LOCATION)
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL

STATICFILES_STORAGE  = 'main.storage_backends.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'main.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
```

**storage_backends.py**

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

StaticRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3Boto3Storage(location='static')

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    file_overwrite = False
```

After running,

> python manage.py collectstatic

I still get the following prompt,

> You have requested to collect static files at the destination
>   location as specified in your settings:
>       /home/drogon/Crowdsocial_project/staticfiles
>
> This will overwrite existing files!
>   Are you sure you want to do this?

It still saves to staticfiles directory locally, not on s3.
What am I doing wrong?

I followed these two tutorials,

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html

https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/s3-static-media-files-for-django/

Comment: can you make sure the `STATICFILES_STORAGE  = 'main.storage_backends.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'` is in right settings file?